# Jenkins Hidden Parameters

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Looking around online and at Jenkins plugins I haven't had any luck finding the solution. Does anyone know if there is a "hidden" parameter available for Parameterized Builds in Jenkins? i.e., I would like to add a parameter type that cannot be changed and does not show up when "Build Now" is pressed.

Comment: The "Environment Injector" plugin does exactly this. It defines parameters from either a script, properties file or in the "Properties Content" field in the project configuration.

Comment: Note: Parameters injected with this plugin cannot be evaluated in other project configuration steps. They will be recognized only by a build script.

Comment: Not sure why you need it to be hidden. Add a dropdown list, make it uneditable and only one choice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the [Hidden Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hidden+Parameter+Plugin).

> Provide `hidden` parameter to Jenkins Jobs. Similar to `string` parameter but not displayed on the UI when triggering the jobs.
>
> Useful when administrators want to enforce some parameters/variables to jobs

Comment: How to access environment variables using `$` symbol in **Hidden parameter's** `Default Value` field under Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

I had a task to pass some parameters from Upstream job to a downstream.
For this purpose I created hidden parameters in downstream job.
As this solution : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hidden+Parameter+Plugin from a post above is unavailable for me, I used ActiveChoiceReactiveReference parameter type with "Formatted hidden HTML" choice type and so it worked to me.